# Azure Devops SSIS Deploy, cannot connect to on prem server

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, ssis, azure-pipelines

I have an SSIS project that I want to use Azure DevOps' CI/CD.
Using SSIS build for the build pipeline, it works.

I have created an agent, installed and configured in the desired on-prem server.
I create an SSIS Deploy for the release pipeline, using the agent.
But I am getting an error, that it cannot connect to the server.

Log snippet:

> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.0917377Z ------------------------------ispac to deploy---------------------------------
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.0967049Z C:\azagent_work\r1\a[XXXX][XXXX][XXXX].ispac
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.0977826Z ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.1047463Z
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.3707323Z ##[error]01/24/2023 03:18:22 Failed to connect to the SQL Server '[XXXX]': Failed to connect to server [XXXX].
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.3720991Z ##[error]01/24/2023 03:18:22 Failed to connect to server [XXXX].
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.3769044Z -----------------------------------Errors-------------------------------------
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.3820946Z ##[error]Failed to connect to the SQL Server '[XXXX]': Failed to connect to server [XXXX].
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.3823079Z
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.3842653Z ##[error]Failed to connect to server [XXXX].
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.3844585Z
> 2023-01-24T03:18:22.4537552Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy SSIS

I can see the ispac file in the server & I can run it manually, but it seems it can't when via Azure Devops.

Appreciate any help... please.

Comment: If the agent is running as a service, does the service account have proper permissions on SQL server? Or the identity is set up differently?

Comment: At the server: the agent is log on as network service.
At SQL; I have set the server: [domain\servername$] as sysadmin

...still the same error

Comment: @HoangMinh Able to do releases now. I had to add the 'agent name' at the 'agent job' setup. As you create the agent: 1- via powershell script at the server, 2- take note of the agent name that you setup. 3- in the agent job step, add the agent name as part of the setup.

Comment: OK so msaybe what happened here is that the deployment job ran on the wrong agent, one that didn't have access to the SQL Server.

Comment: @Nick.Mc It maybe you just need to explicitly setup the right agent that it'll call when the release pipeline triggers. This works for me since I had to setup AZ agents (named uniquely) across diff server environments. And since there is more than 1 agent setup, the pipeline needs to know which agent it'll need to call per environment.

Comment: Yep exactly. it'll just pick any available agent in the pool and it sounds like the agent that it picked was the wrong one

Answer (score 0):

Add the agent name as part of the setup:
[image]

This is what the PS setup at the host server looks like:
[image]